# How do I cut power from USB ports when the laptop is suspended?

Tags: usb, suspend, usb-device

I have a laptop that's always connected to a USB powered cooling fan. When I had windows as the OS, that fan stopped working, on Ubuntu all USB ports are providing power when suspended. Is there a way to cut off power from the USB ports when it's suspended?

Another solution I thought of would be to hibernate instead of suspending, but I don't seem to have that option.

I don't even know where to start to solve this, any idea?

Comment: hibernate *should* work on modern Linux systems. (Reality is sometimes different, sadly). You can potentially power down USB ports!

Comment: I imagined that hibernate would work, but I can't find a way to hibernate my machine.

Comment: If you can't find a software solution, maybe you can apply a hardware solution: on some laptops, only some USB ports are powered when the laptop is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is device `usb1`, what does

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level
```

say?

Assuming you get 'auto' (or 'on' (!)), what happens if you run

```
echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level
```

before suspension?

If that works (**it might not**, in which case we'll have to try something else and kernel and hardware details will probably be needed), then you may want to put that `echo` command either in the startup script or in an executable file named

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/powerdown-usb
```